# Why is my Loop updating the variable outside the loop?

Tags: python

```py
def createChildren(self):
    parentPos = self.pos
    children_list = []
    for i, element in enumerate(parentPos):
        childPos = parentPos
        for n in range(8):
            if element==n:
                pass
            else:
                childPos[i] = n
                children_list.append(EightQueen(childPos))
                        
    return children_list
```

`self.pos` looks like this: `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`
that list is passed on to childPos in the loop, which assigns different values for changing one of the values in childPos.

My goal is to make a list of objects whose self.pos are like

```py
[1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
[2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
[3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
...
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7]
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Just changing **only one number at a time**

The code above returns objects whose `self.pos` are

```py
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[7, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[7, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[7, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[7, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[7, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[7, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[7, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
...
```

Meaning that `parentPos` is being updated everytime it runs through the loop. Why is this happening?

Comment: In Python `=` creates a reference to an object. It does not copy it. So you are always operating on `self.pos`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. Can I just copy the attribute (list) to operate on?

Comment: Try `parentPos = self.pos[:]`!

Comment: That worked great. Thank you!